# Pass knitr parameters to "params" (.GlobalEnv variable) in Visual Studio

Tags: r, visual-studio, knitr

### Background

I often use knitr parameters in interactive mode.

It seems I take for granted the fact that RStudio automatically adds the parameters list to the global environment once I run `knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)`. This does not happen in Visual Studio.

In Visual Studio, I can knit Rmd's without issue, but I'd like access to the parameters as I work inside the Rmd interactively before I knit.

#### Questions

1. What can I do in Visual Studio to pass the parameters to a variable called `params` as auto-magically happens in Rstudio?
2. Is my interactive use of knitr parameters (in RStudio or otherwise) best practice?

### Example `Rmd`

````
---
params:
    x: foo
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{r result}
paste0(params$x, "bar")
```

[1] "foobar"
````

Comment: 1. I would guess there's code somewhere in rmarkdown that retrieves the parameter values from the YAML header.  You'll need to figure out how to tell Visual Studio to use this code to set the variable values.  2.  No, you should use RStudio if you want RStudio behaviour.